# How to close a hung Windows 8.1 Start screen (on multiple monitor setup)

Tags: windows-8.1, task-manager, start-screen

I hit my windows key to launch the start screen immediately after logging into windows. Something is unhappy, as now I can't close the start screen or interact with it in any way.

I've managed to get task manager and chrome up on my other monitor.

What task do I need to close (or run) to kill/restart this frozen Start Screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ending the `explorer.exe` process in task manager, then choose **File->Run new task** and enter `explorer.exe` to restart it.

Comment: That didn't work in this instance, I'd already tried that.  But I'm pretty certain it would be the solution 99% of the time, so I'll mark that as an answer.  This time I'm pretty sure it's the dead hard drive that I've plugged in to try and recover, just bringing certain OS operations to a crawl.  (The Start Screen closed itself before I even saw your response).

Comment: If the drive is faulty then it might well cause the PC to lock up and become unresponsive. Even a bad USB flash drive can bring Windows to its knees sometimes.

Comment: testdisk found it eventually (sat on the "Please Wait..." screen for ten minutes or more).  346 cylinders into 121,603.  This could take a while :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the following statement you made.

> I hit my windows key to launch the start screen immediately after
>   logging into windows. Something is unhappy, as now I can't close the
>   start screen or interact with it in any way.

and

> This time I'm pretty sure it's the dead hard drive that I've plugged
>   in to try and recover, just bringing certain OS operations to a crawl.
>   (The Start Screen closed itself before I even saw your response).

It does indeed sound like Windows is waiting for I/O events from a device that is connected likely the drive you suspect yourself.  As for the specific question you asked you can do the following to force the `Start Screen` to close and `Windows Explorer` to be restarted.

> What task do I need to close (or run) to kill/restart this frozen
>   Start Screen?

The `Start Screen` would be closed if the `Explorer.exe` process is no longer running.  So one would need to simply do the following:

1. Press `CTRL+ALT+DELETE`
2. Select `Start Task Manager` from the `CTRL+ALT+DELETE Screen`
3. Select Explorer.exe
4. Hit `End Task`
5. Hit `File`
6. Select `New Task (Run ...)`
7. Type `Explorer.exe`